# How do I find co-occurring labels?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I have a matrix that is of the shape `n_samples` by `n_features`, where `n_samples` ~ 7000 and `n_features` ~ 800. To clarify, `n_features` are categorical labels, each representing an amino acid position.

I'd like to know which columns have amino acid positions which are highly correlated with each other. For example, one might have a protein where amino acid position 255 = H when 288 = Y ("HY" combination), and 255 = N when 288 = P ("NP" combination). This is a completely hypothetical scenario, btw. In the data set, I might find, for example, 3500 instances of HY, 100 instances of HP, 3400 instances of NP. In this case, we would say that position 255 and 288 are correlated with each other.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to compute this. Using scikit-learn, I have transformed the data into numerical categorical labels, where an amino acid position is now represented by numbers (i.e. from 0 to 20). So now, it's `rows=each sequence`, and `columns=each position`, and the `numbers in each cell=0 to 20`, each letter represented by a number.

What would your advice be for going from this data matrix to finding columns that "covary" together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the bioinformatics literature, this is known as sequence coevolution. Disclaimer: I'm an author. [See this article.](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0038114)

I'm familiar with one branch of the literature. The early literature on coevolution formed positional covariance using $\chi^2$ measures. Someone got the idea to compare positional covariance to structural contact maps derived from pdbs. When compared in this way normalized mutual information handedly beats $\chi^2$ metrics. Several other metrics, such as SCA(which means a number of things, but probably means inner product), sum-of-squares-methods et al. have fell by the wayside. Normalized mutual information was improved upon by z-scoring away phylogenetic background for positions. I'm not sure where the literature is currently.

Comment: Many thanks, Jacob. I am a novice in this area, so I'm lacking in some depth of knowledge here. Would you be able to help me evaluate whether the NMI implemented in scikit-learn's `sklearn.metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score` would be suitable for calculating the NMI used in your paper? Or would I have to do something else manually?

Comment: That's roughly the same calculation if you map amino acid to integers. There's a few different meanings for NMI, I chose joint entropy normalization. I wrote a python library towards the end up the paper. https://github.com/JakeMick/pycoevolve The paper was done in Matlab, but this library gave me identical results for clusters, despite that the bootstrapping being stochastic. What do you plan on doing with the results? I'd be happy to clean up the code and write some docs.

Comment: I'm using the results as a way of finding epistatic residues in the influenza genome. One of the research scientists in our lab will be looking at that list of residues to see if he can identify the ones important for switching host specificities in the influenza virus.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain what joint entropy normalization refers to? I wasn't able to catch that in your paper.

Comment: Mutual information is biased by the conservation at positions. You can effectively eliminate conservation at positions, unless that position is ultra-conserved, by normalizing by the entropy at the positions. There's several normalizing entropy terms you could use. Joint entropy is one such term.

Comment: Mmm, I see. Can I just confirm one small detail: By normalizing, you refer to division, am I correct? i.e. divide the mutual information score by the joint entropy?

Comment: Right! Without the normalization by joint entropy, the mutual information is biased by conversation at the individual positions. Apparently equally as important is to normalize somehow by the total covariation of a column.

Comment: Hmm... may I ask, what do you mean by "total covariation of a column"? Or did you mean 'total covariation between two columns'?

Comment: Sorry, 'Total co-variation between the two columns' is correct. You form a contingency table between columns. Single variable entropy terms are performed on the marginals, $H(X) = \sum_x x log(x)$, The two variable entropy term is computed by the same calculation over the flattened contingency table. Joint Entropy Normalized Mutual Information is then given by $2(H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y)) / H(X,Y)$. Intuitively it's similar to $\chi^2$ in that it compares the observed contingency to the expected contingency under independence assumptions. It happens to map better as a distance metric though.

Comment: This is really helpful, Jacob! Might you have the paper/reference that helped you decide that this was the right measure, or that describes this form or normalization of MI?

Comment: I cross-validated over the options. Check out the papers by Gloor GB. All of his are great. "Validation of coevolving residue algorithms via pipeline sensitivity analysis: ELSC and OMES and ZNMI, oh my!" also was a primary influence on the paper.